# Printing one character at a time from a string, using the while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Im reading "Core Python Programming 2nd Edition", They ask me to print a string, one character at a time using a "while" loop.

I know how the while loop works, but for some reason i can not come up with an idea how to do this. I've been looking around, and only see examples using for loops.

So what i have to do:

user gives input:

```
text = raw_input("Give some input:  ")
```

I know how to read out each piece of data from an array, but i can't remember anything how to do it to a string.

Now all i need is working while-loop, that prints every character of the string, one at a time.

i guess i've to use len(text), but i'm not 100% sure how to use it in this problem.

Some help would be awsome! I'm sure this is a very simple issue, but for some reason i cannot come up with it!

Thx in advance! :)

Comment: Please add some code to show us what you have tried, that would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm quite sure, that the internet is full of python while-loops, but one example:

```
i=0

while i < len(text):
    print text[i]
    i += 1
```

Comment: Yes, the internet is full of python while-loops :) i've used them before. But i couldn't completely figure out how to let it print 1 character of a string at a time! Thx for your help!

Comment: You might want to read the Python tutorial => [Strings](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Answer (score 6):

Strings can have for loops to:

```
for a in string:
    print a
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have already given you the code you need to iterate though a string using a `while` loop (or a `for` loop) but I thought it might be useful to explain the difference between the two types of loops.

`while` loops repeat some code until a certain condition is met. For example:

```
import random

sum = 0
while sum < 100:
    sum += random.randint(0,100) #add a random number between 0 and 100 to the sum
    print sum
```

This code will keep adding random numbers between 0 and 100 until the total is greater or equal to 100. The important point is that this loop could run exactly once (if the first random number is 100) or it could run forever (if it keeps selecting 0 as the random number). We can't predict how many times the loop will run until after it completes.

`for` loops are basically just while loops but we use them when we want a loop to run a preset number of times. Java `for` loops usually use some sort of a counter variable (below I use `i`), and generally makes the similarity between `while` and `for` loops much more explicit.

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) { //starting from 0, until i is 10, adding 1 each iteration
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

This loop will run exactly 10 times. This is just a nicer way to write this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) { //until i is 10
   System.out.println(i);
   i++; //add one to i 
}
```

The most common usage for a for loop is to iterate though a list (or a string), which Python makes very easy:

```
for item in myList:
    print item
```

or

```
for character in myString:
    print character
```

However, you didn't want to use a `for` loop. In that case, you'll need to look at each character using its index. Like this:

```
print myString[0] #print the first character
print myString[len(myString) - 1] # print the last character.
```

Knowing that you can make a `for` loop using only a `while` loop and a counter and knowing that you can access individual characters by index, it should now be easy to access each character one at a time using a `while` loop.

**HOWEVER** in  general you'd use a `for` loop in this situation because it's easier to read.

Comment: This was very helpfull! I know how to work with both, but this makes me have more sense about what im doing! Thx alot! :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this procedure:

```
def procedure(input):
    a=0
    print input[a]
    ecs = input[a] #ecs stands for each character separately
    while ecs != input:
        a = a + 1
        print input[a]
```

In order to use it you have to know how to use procedures and although it works, it has an error in the end so you have to work that out too.

Answer (score 1):

Python allows you to use a string as an iterator:

```
for character in 'string':
    print(character)
```

I'm guessing it's your job to figure out how to turn that into a while loop.

Comment: You are correct and this is the way people would iterate through a string 99.9% of the time but the OP explicitly states they don't want to use a `for` loop

Comment: I figured I wouldn't flatout provide the answer as this seems to be an assignment, but provide the hint that `str` is iterable in itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
   # make a list out of text - ['h','e','l','l','o']
   text = list('hello') 

   while text:
       print text.pop()
```

:)

In python empty object are evaluated as false.
The .pop() removes and returns the last item on a list. And that's why it prints on reverse !

But can be fixed by using:

```
text.pop( 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Python Code:

```
for s in myStr:
        print s
```

OR

```
for i in xrange(len(myStr)):
    print myStr[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead ...

### Printing each character using while loop

```
i=0
x="abc"
while i<len(x) :
    print(x[i],end=" ")
    print(i)
    i+=1
```

Comment: The answer is good, but it would be great getting some details about the solution, especially since the question evolving basic and fundamentals aspects of programming, which means the person who asks is probably a novice. 

And to the point:
a. What is the end param (I'm guessing adding space after each character)
b. Printing the index (i) is not needed, but I suspect you used it for debugging and more clarity while running your solution

Comment: Yes..printing index is not needed...but to know the how code works...i used it on beginner level

Comment: Sure, it is a good idea to do that, I was just pointing it is worth putting a comment on that line telling it is to help understanding and not really needed for the solution.

Answer (score -2):

This will print each character in text

```
text = raw_input("Give some input:  ")
for i in range(0,len(text)):
   print(text[i])
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes it does. How to iterate over string basically.

Comment: The question asked explicitly for a while-loop.