# Print a inputted word from 1 to all letters, increasing by 1 letter per output line

Tags: python

I would like so my code would print out this but I really dont know how, Im a beginner.:

Give word : `something`

```
s
so
som
some
somet
someth
somethi
somethin
something
```

this is what I got but I dont know how to make it so it works with input

```
word = input("Give word: ")

length = len(word)
while True:
    print(word[0:1])
```

Comment: Hi, please write a *summarized* title that describes the problem. *Be specific and imagine you are talking to a busy colleague*. Currently your title does not give any meaningful information about the post at all, the "thank you" statement there is also not necessary at all. So please edit your title into a summarized title that actually describes the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing one character at a time from a string, using the while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221516/printing-one-character-at-a-time-from-a-string-using-the-while-loop)

Answer (score 1):

```py
word = input('Some word: ')
for i in range(0, len(word)):
    print(word[:i+1])
```

result:

```
s
so
som
some
somet
someth
somethi
somethin
something
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you required:

1.

```
word = input("Give word: ")
count = 0
res = ''
while count < len(word):
    res += word[count]
    print(res)
    count += 1
```

2. 

```
word = input("Give word: ")
count = 0

while count < len(word):
    print(word[:count + 1])
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you :

```
word = "something"
cc =""
for x in word:
   cc += x
   print(cc)
```

result :

```
s
so
som
some
somet
someth
somethi
somethin
something
```

Process finished with exit code 0